# Pass data to modal from other url

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

What I try to do is pass data from main page to popup page(modal) that I call from other html.
What I want to pass is name and description that exist in main to modal.

My main

```
<a href="v?PageId=frmGroupGeneral" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editGroup">EDIT</a>

<div id="editGroup" class="modal fade text-center">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My frmGroupGeneral html(modal/popup)

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
        <h1>Group Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="container-fluid text-left">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1">
              <p>Name</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-11">
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" id="textareaName" placeholder="Enter name" maxlength="50"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1">
              <p>Description</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-11">
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="textareaDescription" placeholder="Enter description" maxlength="500"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using the `*data` attributes in your html page. All you have to do is to add few more data-* id's according to your need to pass the data from your parent html page to the popup page.

For eg,

Considering your case you can pass the name and description to your modal like this,

```
<a href="v?PageId=frmGroupGeneral" data-toggle="modal" data-name="YOUR_NAME_VALUE" data-description="YOUR_DESCRIPTION" data-target="#editGroup">EDIT</a>
```

And in your modal you can retrieve the passed in parameters as,

```
 var nameValue = $(this).data('name');
 var descriptionValue = $(this).data('description');
```

To set the retrieved value to any field in model you can simply do,

```
 $(".modal-body #textareaName").val(nameValue);
 $(".modal-body #textareaDescription").val(descriptionValue);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: so `var ....` I will put in frmGroupGeneral html and  `$(".modal-body .........);` in main? Sorry I quiet new in this.

Comment: You need to add `data-name="YOUR_NAME_VALUE" data-description="YOUR_DESCRIPTION"` to your `main` file and `var... and $(".modal-body #textareaName...)` in your popup.

Comment: I already but when I use `debugger;` to see the value. It show nothing.

Comment: Can you please put up your code in a fiddle and give me a working link to check?

Comment: Okay.. I've putup an working example for you here => http://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/6118/  Do check it out..

Comment: Okay actually it work. But it only work when second time I click on that button. Any solution?

Comment: Even I put the script in main. It still can work but it the same problem when I put it in other html. I need to close modal and click again than it show in textarea. When I put debugger, it actually go inside of that script but I don't know why first time cannot work. Still struggle with this. Btw thanks for your help. Appreciate it. Maybe need to open new topic to ask for this thing. Thank you again.